# Make a TestProbe to forget all the messgaes

Tags: scala, akka, testkit

I am writing a code in a test driven way, and after having written many tests, I introduced a new actor, and in my test environment I use a TestProbe for it.
Now in the n-th test, I am testing that the new actor receives a message.
But the message he actually receives is not the expected one, because he receives many message from other tests, before the expected one.
So is there a way to tell the TestProbe to forget all the messages received until now, without specifying the number, and start listening the messages from now?

Some code:

```
class MyTest  extends TestKit(ActorSystem("test")) {

  var myActorRef: ActorRef = _
  var myTestProbe = TestProbe()

  before {
    myActorRef = system.actorOf(MyActor.props(myTestProbe.ref))
  }

  "MyActor" must {

    //.... many tests here

    "trigger notification to myTestProbe" in {
        // here I would like myTestProbe to forget all the messages he received before
          myActorRef ! AMessageThatShoudCauseAnotherMessageToBeSentToMyProbe(..)


      myProbe.expectMsg(
        TheExpectedMessage(...) //this fails, because the message received has been sent before this test.
      )
    }
```

I can do `myTestProbe.receiveN(200)` but I need the exact number of messages, and if I then add another test before, this number could change... it's really bad.

I could also to re-create the testProbe and the actor under test:

```
myTestProbe = TestProbe()
myActorRef = system.actorOf(MyActor.props(myTestProbe.ref))
```

but for other reasons, I would prefer to avoid it... any other suggestion?

Comment: I would use a new `TestProbe` beforeEach test as it is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: yes, at the end it is what I did, thank you.